# Leaving job after 3 weeks but now want to return... after 6 months

Tags: resignation, retail

I'm going to use the company names to keep this simple to follow.

I started working for Zara retail in August 2015. My Head Cashier and some of the staff weren't exactly nice to me. I would go to work in a good, positive mood but return indoors in a really bad mood. I didn't feel valued. The Head Cashier spoke to me in a condescending manner. I contacted the HR team, who then spoke to the Head of the Department. I had a meeting with him and the Head Cashier, which honestly felt like they were ganging up on me. I didn't want to leave the company but I also didn't want to put up with uneccessary mental grief, especially when I did nothing to deserve it. I handed in my resignation after completing the third week due to numerous inconsistencies and the treatment by the Head Cashier. I didn't get paid correctly either after leaving, so had to chase that up too. After speaking to a new Senior member of the team at the store this was agreed. I haven't returned to the store or spoken to any members since leaving in September 2015.

I now want to re-apply but to Zara Home. My concerns are that although I have now been invited to attend the Recruitment centre, they will ask why I left Zara Retail only after 3 weeks. Although I would like to say that the Head Cashier was being a condescending and difficult @rse for no good reason, I know that I can't say anything negative about him, or the team at the store. My reason for returning is that I would like to to try a different department of retail (home/furnishings). I don't know whether I should say that I didn't give Zara retail much of a chance so I would like to retry. I also realise that they may say 'no' to me if they think I'll end up leaving again.

Any other reasons/advice would be welcomed.

Comment: No matter your chances, it never hurts to ask -- it's not a huge investment of your time, and the worst case is that they say no. Agree with @JoeStrazzere -- you'll need to come up with a diplomatic version of the truth, such as "communication difficulties." Something like "personal conflicts" could reflect negatively on you.

Comment: Waste of time, there is no way leaving after just three weeks can be made to look good.

Comment: I think you should first find out through HR if you're eligible for rehire.

Answer (score 2):

Given what you've described, I don't see why you would want to return to the same company. You had problems with the Head Cashier which you brought up with HR, but HR wasn't able to address anything. You then resigned, but Payroll messed up your paycheck. That sounds like a terrible experience.

If you must go back and you will be asked why you left the company after such a short period of time. If you say you wanted to pursue another opportunity, you look flaky. If you mention, your previous experience with the Head Cashier, you look like someone who doesn't play nice with others even if the other person you felt was at fault. If you were looking at different position, say Sales Associate, you could say the position wasn't a good fit for your skill set, but again you'll be faced with why did you leave so quickly? Your best hope is someone else who can voucher for you such as a manager or another lead position.

Comment: Judging by the responses I've received above it's become clear which route I should follow. Its always helpful to see the objective viewpoint. I can't elaborate on the whole situation but thank you to those who have written a reply. I genuinely appreciate it.